# get JSON expression in a object

Tags: java, json

In this expression :

```
obj: {"created":"2017/02/09 15:57","fields":{"summary":"(30) #F24 Emarsys ==> Mise à jour du fichier de transfert / Dépriorisé en attendant PARDOT","issuetype":{"name":"Task"},"created":"589c8377576a33706397f3f4","
```

I think It's a trivial question but I don't arrive to get this expression :

```
obj: {"created":"2017/02/09 15:57" ...
```

I do :

```
String created2 = obj.getJSONObject("fields").getString("created");
```

but I get :

```
"created":"589c8377576a33706397f3f4"
```

I don't succeed to get the first element "created".

Please could you advice me to do this stuff.

Comment: You're getting the correct behavior. If multiple fields by the same name are found in a JSON object, the last one wins.

Comment: hi, Ah really ?!

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC7159, "The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6):

> When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
> only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
> object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
> including duplicates.

You are seeing the first option, "Many implementations report the last name/value pair only". Generally speaking, it is best to keep the keys within a JSON object unique.

Comment: I made a confusion with the method "put" : obj.put("created",formatted);. For this reason, I had twice the key "created". Indeed I search to replace " "created":"589c8377576a33706397f3f4"" " by "created":"2017/02/09 15:57"

Answer (score 0):

OK fellows, I found the solution :

To insert my famous date in the field `"created"`, I do :

```
obj.getJSONObject("fields").put("created",formatted);
```

Finally, I get :

```
obj : {"fields":{"summary":"(30) #F24 Emarsys ==> Mise à jour du fichier de transfert / Dépriorisé en attendant PARDOT","issuetype":{"name":"Task"},"created":"2017/02/09 15:57","project":
```

Thanks at all !

Ale